# Из-за чего несколько раз инициируется событие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Описание**: 
При нажатии на кнопку (назовем ее "Первая") аяксом подгружается форма, 
в форме checkbox, при нажатии на него 
с помощью jquery функции slideToggle отображается другая форма.

Все отрабатывает корректно до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажимает "Первую кнопку", после новой генерации формы, события внутри ее отрабатывают несколько раз.

**Пример**: 
Сгенерировали форму аяксом, нажали на элемент вызывающий событие внутри формы - все нормально. 
**Перегенерировали форму** ( прошлая форма была удаленна .empty("") ),
нажали на интерактивный элемент внутри, событие вызвалось 2 раза. 
**Перегенерировали форму** ( прошлая форма была удаленна .empty("") ),
нажали на интерактивный элемент внутри, событие вызвалось 3 раза. 
**Перегенерировали форму** ( прошлая форма была удаленна .empty("") ),
нажали на интерактивный элемент внутри, событие вызвалось 4 раза и т.д.

В чем может быть проблема (сам скрипт снизу)?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Добавить клиента
    $("body").on("mousedown", "#addClient", function () {
        if (event.which == 1) {
            // Подгружаем необходимые поля
            $.ajax({
                url: "../new_client.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    if ($.find(".grid_content_ajax .newClient__wrapper").length != 0) {
                        $(".grid_content_ajax .newClient__wrapper").remove();
                    }
                    $(".grid_content_ajax").empty().append("<div class='newClient__wrapper' style='display: none;'>" + data + "</div>");
                    $(".newClient__wrapper").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
                }
            });

            // При фокусе на элемент формы "Добавить клиента"
            $(".grid_content_ajax").on("focus", ".addClient__input", function () {
                $(".addClient__item").removeClass("addClient__item_active");
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("addClient__item_active");
            });
            $(".grid_content_ajax").on("blur", ".addClient__input", function () {
                $(".addClient__item").removeClass("addClient__item_active");
            });

            // Добавить представителя
            $(".grid_content_ajax").on("mousedown", "#addAgent", function (event) {
                if (event.which == 1) {
                    $( this ).find(".addClient__mark").toggleClass("icon-mark");
                    $(".addClient__wrapperAgent").slideToggle();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форма новая, а ивенты с привязкой к классам остались.
Необходимо либо их сбрасывать, либо учитывать повтор назначения.
Либо, что проще, вынести из обработчика бади в инициализацию, например, doc.onready

Comment: Вынес на уровень выше в doc.ready, все заработало, спасибо